# Does E ~ F select multiple elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/ the selector `E ~ F` matches "an F element preceded by an E element". I'm confused as to whether this means only a single F, or any F preceded by E.

For example, should the selector:

```
E ~ F.blah
```

match only the first F which is both preceded by E and has class "blah", or *all* such elements?

Comment: Selectors level 3 is already a recommendation, and has changed substantially since the 2001 CR (in particular, `::selection` and `:contains()` are gone). You'll want to refer to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors which is the latest recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches any and all such elements as long as they're under the same parent.

Unlike the adjacent sibling combinator `+`, the general sibling combinator `~` doesn't require an element to immediately follow another element. Since there is no such positional restriction, `~` doesn't carry any first-match semantics. (In fact, neither does `+`, but it's still more restricted in that sense; see below.)

This also means if an element matches `E + F.blah`, it must also by definition match `E ~ F.blah`. Conversely, not every element matching `E ~ F.blah` will also match `E + F.blah`.

An illustration:

```
<E></E>
<D>
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- Not selected [1] -->
    <E></E>
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- E + F.blah, E ~ F.blah [2] -->
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- E ~ F.blah only [3] -->
    <F></F>
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- E ~ F.blah only [3] -->
    <E></E>
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- E + F.blah, E ~ F.blah [4] -->
</D>
<D>
    <F class="blah"></F> <!-- Not selected [5] -->
</D>
```

What's selected and what's not:

1. **Not selected**
   This F element has class "blah", but it is not preceded by an E element in its parent D.

   Note that the topmost E is a preceding sibling of D, not F, so it isn't counted.
2. **Selected by `E + F.blah` and `E ~ F.blah`**
   This F element is preceded by an E element in its parent D, and it has class "blah", so it matches the selector `E ~ F.blah`.

   Since the E element lies **immediately** before this F element, it also matches `E + F.blah`.
3. **Selected by `E ~ F.blah` only**
   This F element is preceded by an `E` element in its parent D, and it has class "blah". However, the E in this case is no longer the immediately-preceding sibling, this element won't match `E + F.blah`.
4. **Selected by `E + F.blah` and `E ~ F.blah`**
   Although the first E element doesn't lie immediately before this F element, there is a second E element which does occur immediately before it, so it also matches `E + F.blah`.

   By the way, this element will match the selector `E:first-of-type ~ F.blah` *but not* the selector `E:first-of-type + F.blah`, since its preceding sibling E is not the first of its type, but the second.
5. **Not selected**
   This F element has class "blah", but it is not preceded by any E elements in its parent D, because it's in a different parent D from all the E elements in the example (as well as being its only child).

For what it's worth, it's not possible to select only the first element that matches `E ~ F.blah` (unless it also matches `E + F.blah`, in which case you can just use that instead). However, if you're applying CSS rules, it can be achieved using an override — just repeat the sibling combinator:

```
E ~ F.blah {
    /* Styles for first and following E ~ F.blah */
}

E ~ F.blah ~ F.blah {
    /* Styles for only F.blah following the first E ~ F.blah */
}
```

Comment: it's a shame ~ doesn't carry any first-match semantics, it's exactly what I need right now!